# Regexp replace for mutil-line

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I need to replace a string between two lines. For example:

`"aaa\nfoo\nfoo\naaa\nfoo\nbbb\nfoo\nbbb"` ==> `"aaa\nfoo\nfoo\naaa\nright\nbbb\nfoo\nbbb"`

I want to use perl like following format but failed:

```
echo -e "aaa\nfoo\nfoo\naaa\nfoo\nbbb\nfoo\nbbb" | perl -pe "code here"
```

So is there a good way to deal with it?

Both `perl` and `awk` is ok.

Comment: what pattern do you want to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl:

```
echo -e "aaa\nfoo\nfoo\naaa\nfoo\nbbb\nfoo\nbbb" | perl -p00e 's/aaa\nfoo\nbbb/aaa\nright\nbbb/'
```

if you need to match a pattern multiline, you must change the record separator. the flags m and s can be useful too.

see also

```
perl --help         # -0
perldoc perlvar     # $/
perldoc perlre      # /Modifiers
perl -MO=Deparse -p00e 's/aaa\nfoo\nbbb/aaa\nright\nbbb/'
```

Awk:

```
echo -e "aaa\nfoo\nfoo\naaa\nfoo\nbbb\nfoo\nbbb" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{sub(/aaa\nfoo\nbbb/,"aaa\nright\nbbb",$0);print}'
```

Comment: @dan1111 Doc links might be a good idea but not in the middle of a code block.